# Problema de bindig en WPF con MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Estoy trabajando en una pequeña solución que contiene dos proyectos.
Uno es una fuente de datos y el otro un WPF con MVVM.
El código está subido en 
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=53E66796566CD052%21125&cid=53E66796566CD052

El caso es que cuando abro una ventana nueva desde la MainWindow por medio de un botón con su correspondiente comando, 
el ViewModel de la nueva ventana no me bindea correctamente con la vista.
el DataContext de la ventana me trae correctamente los target de la 
fuente de datos.

La vista tiene este código:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="26,30" Width="68">
        <Label Content="Nombre      :   " Margin="0,0,0,10"></Label>
        <Label Content="Apellidos   :   " Margin="0,0,0,10"></Label>
        <Label Content="Direccion   :   " Margin="0,0,0,10"></Label>
        <Label Content="Contacto    :   " Margin="0,0,0,10"></Label>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Margin="40,30" Width="220" 
       DataContext = "{Binding}" >
    <TextBox x:Name="txtNombre" Width="160" Margin="0,6,0,18" 
           Text="{ Binding Path=Nombre
           ,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtApellidos" Width="160" Margin="0,0,0,18"
          Text="{BindingPath=Apellidos,
           Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtDireccion" Width="160" Margin="0,0,0,18"
         Text="{ Binding Path=TempPersona.Direccion,    Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtContacto" Width="160" Margin="0,0,0,18" 
        Text="{ Binding Path=TempPersona.Contacto,  Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
 </StackPanel>
 <StackPanel Orientation ="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
   Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="70,0" Width="280">
    <Button Content="Limpiar" Height="30" Width="120"  Margin="0,0,20,10"                
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Command="{Binding 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
          AncestorType={x:Type  Window}}, Path=DataContext.ClearAVM}">
    </Button>
        <Button Content="Añadir" Height="30" 
             Width="120" Margin="20,0,0,10"
                CommandParameter ="{Binding }" 
                Command="{Binding 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource  
           AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.AnadirAVM}">
   </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

En El Codebehind :

```
public partial class AnadirView : Window
{
    public AnadirView(AnadirViewModel avm)
    {
        //AnadirViewModel avm = new AnadirViewModel(target);

        this.DataContext = avm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

Y el ViewModewl :

```
public class AnadirViewModel : NotifyBase
{
    public IFactory targetAVM { get; set; }

    private Persona _tempPersona;
    public Persona TempPersona
    {
        get { return _tempPersona; }
        set
        {
            if (_tempPersona != value) //(1)
            {
                _tempPersona = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("TempPersona");
            }
         }
    }
   // public AnadirViewModel() { }
    public AnadirViewModel(IFactory factory)
    {
        targetAVM = factory;

        AnadirView anadir = new AnadirView(this);
        anadir.Width = 400;
        anadir.Height = 400;
        anadir.ShowDialog();

    }
 ...
private ICommand _anadirAVM;
    public ICommand AnadirAVM
    {
    get { return _anadirAVM ??  //(2)
            (_anadirAVM = new RelayCommand((parameter) =>  AnadirAVMAction(parameter))); }
    }

    private void AnadirAVMAction(object parameter)
    {        
        TempPersona = parameter as Persona;
        targetAVM.Crear(TempPersona);
        targetAVM.GetAll();
        MessageBox.Show("Registro Añadir");
    }
```

Aquí parameter siempre llega nulo ,porque la propiedad TempPersona no se actualiza. En (1) y (2) está el fallo.
 TempPersona es una propiedad presente en cada target
 La idea es poder cambiar en caliente desde un menú el la MainWindow
y poder insertar, borrar editar etc.
 He conseguido cambiar los target ( MOCData y EFData ) y borrar correctamente, pero a la hora de añadir no me bindea los values de los 
Textbox con la propiedad TempPersona. Es un problema de diseño ??
 A alguien se le ocurre algo?

Un saludo y gracias.César

He descubierto que el problema puede provenir del MainWindow.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
            <Button x:Name="Buscar" Height="40" Width="180"   Margin="20" Content="Buscar" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"  
                        Command="{Binding Buscar}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnAnadir"  Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Añadir"  
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Command="{Binding Anadir}"/>
                <!--Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Anadir}"/>-->
                <Button x:Name="btnNuevo"   Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Editar" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"
                        Command="{Binding Editar}"/>
                <!--Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Editar}"/>-->
                <Button x:Name="btnBorrar"  Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Borrar"  
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"  
                        Command="{Binding Borrar}" />
                <Button x:Name="btnOpen"    Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Visual"  
                       Style="{StaticResource BigFontButton}"
                        CommandParameter="" Command="{Binding Visual}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ListView x:Name="ListViewPersonas" Grid.Row="1" Height="420" Width="520" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path= DalPersona, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" >
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView x:Name="grdPersonas" >
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Nombre"    x:Name="Nombre"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nombre,     Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Width="160" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Apellidos" x:Name="Apellido" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Apellido,   Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Width="160" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Contacto"  x:Name="Contacto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Contacto,   Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Width="220" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
```

Todos los botones tiene un CommandParameter vinculado al item
seleccionado en el ListView, excepto el de Añadir.
Alguna idea par solucionarlo ?

Gracias anticipadas y un sludo.
César

Comment: Lo PRIMERO que haría es definir el ViewModel en el etiquetado XAML, en la parte superior a través de un xmlns. Así te ahorras el prefijo 'DataContext' en cada Binding o ICommand.

Lo SEGUNDO, TempPersona lo instancearía enseguida: private Persona _tempPersona = new Persona();


Lo TERCERO al llamar Agregar, usaría un ICommand sin parámetros pues la Persona ya está arriba instanceada, y si la operación es exitosa entonces reseteo los valores para crear una nueva Persona.

Por cierto, tu link no abre, está oculto?

Comment: Gracias Leodev.Te dejo otro link en Drive :https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o3yKMqVridaM_6Frjt8tPEV4d83Fdcn8

Comment: Buenas.He hecho una modificación en el código.Antes TempPersona estaba en el DAL , ahora he creado un ViewModelBase del que heredan todos los ViewModels y funciona bastante bien. Lo único es que EFData, aunque añade el registro a la base de datos ,no refresca la UI.https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MTBlftqXLZi0gRGMlGaKD4OxyXqLVCNY

Comment: Tienes implementado INotifyPropertyChanged en las clases de los objetos que se despliegan en la UI?

Comment: Si, está implementado en el ViewModelBase del que heredan los demás.Lo gracioso es que Editar si me refresca la UI, pero Añadir no ,en el DAL de Entity Framework. Depurando me dice que  "La evaluación de la función requiere que se ejecuten todos los subprocesos". He intentado implementar un  public async Task<List<Persona>> GetAllAsync()  pero eso creo que me fuerza a crear otra variable Lista para el DAL de Entity Framework.

Comment: SOLVED : He añadido ADONetData y XMLData y he resuelto el problema de refresco de la UI. He subido el código a https://drive.google.com/open?id=1APFVNABDQ8Mk_Y33kbUz5nNYkcZJkgSF