# TreeView en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Continuando con la solución de [Problema de bindig en WPF con MVVM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198622/problema-de-bindig-en-wpf-con-mvvm), en la que ya conseguí que me respondieran los DAL (`MOCData`,`EFData`,`AdoNetData` y `XMLData`) , ahora trato de poder cambiar el `ListView` de la `MainWindow` por un `TreeView`, pero me encuentro con el problema de que los botones que manipulan los datos están bindeados al `ListView`.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
                <Button x:Name="btnBuscar" Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Buscar" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"  
                        Command="{Binding Buscar}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnAnadir"  Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Añadir"  
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"

                         CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"  

                        Command="{Binding Anadir}"/>
                <!--Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Anadir}"/>-->
                <Button x:Name="btnNuevo"   Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Editar" 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"
                        Command="{Binding Editar}"/>
                <!--Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Editar}"/>-->
                <Button x:Name="btnBorrar"  Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Borrar"  
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"  
                        Command="{Binding Borrar}" />
                <Button x:Name="btnOpen"    Height="40" Width="180" Margin="20" Content="Visual"  
                       Style="{StaticResource BigFontButton}"
                        CommandParameter="" Command="{Binding Visual}"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

por medio del CommandParameter.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonas, Path=SelectedItems}"
```

He intentado en CodeBehind lo siguiente :

```
private void CambiarView(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String str = sender.ToString();

        if (str.Contains( "List"))
        {
            ScrollList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ScrollTree.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
        else
        {
            ScrollList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ScrollTree.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnAnadir.CommandParameter = "{Binding ElementName=TreeViewPersonas, Path=SelectedValuePath}";
            btnBorrar.CommandParameter = "{Binding ElementName=TreeViewPersonas, Path=SelectedValuePath}";
            btnBuscar.CommandParameter = "{Binding ElementName=TreeViewPersonas, Path=SelectedValuePath}";
        }         
    }
```

pero la solución no me funciona.¿ Cómo puedo determinar el `itemSelected` en un `TreeView` ?

Gracias anticipadas y un saludo.
César

Comment: `TreeView` tiene una propiedad `SelectedItem` (ojo,en singular)

Comment: Gracias Pikoh pero tampoco me funciona.De todas formas este TreeView es un control que no acabo de entender bien.Hay por ahí algún sitio con algún ejemplo que bindee una Lista ?

Comment: El treeview no tiene una propiedad selecteditem bindeable, tienes que usar el evento SelectedItemChanged

Comment: Gracias Luis,ese sería el segundo problema , pero creo que eso no me soluciona el primer problema ya que tengo que ser capaz de cambiar el ElementName del binding de los botones en el XAML, o bien eliminando el binding del XAML y hacerlo por código, o algo que no se si es muy descabellado : crear una DependencyProperty asociada a los botones, y que sea ahí donde se discrimine el escenario.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : En CodeBehind al cambiar la Vista

```
private void CambiarView(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String str = sender.ToString();

        if (str.Contains( "List"))
        {
            ScrollList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ScrollTree.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            Binding bindingBuscar = new Binding();

            bindingBuscar.ElementName = "ListViewPersonas";
            bindingBuscar.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem");
            bindingBuscar.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            btnBuscar.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, bindingBuscar);
        }
```

Un binding para cada botón y objetivo(ListView y TreeView), un poco redundante pero de momento funciona bien. Tendré que buscar la forma de reducir el código con alguna Lista de Botones o algo así.

Un saludo.César.

Comment: Código subido a https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w2cRQsAD_8OT_DvVfcOpiPMUnsWT9RDM